# What is the difference between asynchrony in c# and in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asynchronous, event-loop

In python and js, there is often a problem associated with blocking the event loop, when the code is executed in one thread and only one synchronous operation can be performed at the same time, but I could not find this problem anywhere in C#, maybe this problem does not exist in C#, if not, then why? And what is the difference between asynchrony in C# and javascript

Answer (score 0):

c# actually has multiple threads, so whenever asynchronous coding is used it should either run on a background thread, or use asynchronous IO provided by the OS, so no thread is actually used at all for the operation.

c# UI programs still have a UI thread with an event loop, and it is perfectly possible to deadlock if you use poor programming practices. As an example:

```
Task task = SomeAsynchronousOperation();
task.Wait(); // can deadlock if run on the UI thread
```

The reason is that SomeAsynchronousOperation might need to run something on the UI thread to complete, and this is obviously not possible if it is waiting a task.

But it is also fairly easy to solve in c#

```
Task task = SomeAsynchronousOperation();
await task; // No deadlock
```

By the magic of the compiler rewriting your method into a state machine the risk of deadlock is removed.